# Call phtml file in CMS page not working Magento2

Tags: php, magento, module, magento2

I am building a module for which I need to call my view file in the CMS page, which is located at `app\code\Eecom\Atc\view\frontend\templates\atc\index.phtml`.

And in the CMS I am calling this file as:

```
    {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
template="atc/index.phtml" }}
```

I have also tried:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Eecom_Atc::atc/ndex.phtml"}}
```

but both are not working. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

The below code is working:

```
 {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Eecom_Atc::atc/ndex.phtml"}}
```

The issue was the cache flush.

Comment: This helped.  What I was missing was 'view/frontend'.  Every other question/answer I saw just said 'put file in templates directory'.

Comment: Good to hear .It helped :)